# Centering the message of a DialogFragment without a custom layout file

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to add a center gravity to the message of a dialog fragment without having a separate XML file for a custom layout. I've tried getting the TextView and setting the gravity of that, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Replace current sound");
        builder.setMessage("Choose a mp3 or ogg file or restore the default sound.\nThe current sound is:\n"+currentSound)
               .setPositiveButton("Choose new sound", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // This is the Choose File dialog (uses aFileDialog library)
                    // to get the file replacement
                    FileChooserDialog dialog1 = new FileChooserDialog(context);
                    dialog1.show();
                    dialog1.addListener(new OnFileSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFileSelected(Dialog source, File file) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            source.hide();
                            Log.e("App Debugging", file.getAbsolutePath());
                            String fileReplacement = file.getAbsolutePath();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFileSelected(Dialog source, File folder,
                                String name) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Restore default", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show(); 
        TextView messageText = TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
```

EDIT: Here are my findings so far: I can get it to work if I add another `builder.show();` call after setting the `messageText` gravity, but that leads to another dialog popping up right after closing the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try like this

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show(); 
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message); 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) messageText.getLayoutParams();
p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
messageText.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: That seems to give me a NullPointerException. In fact, I get a NullPointerException whenever I try to do anything with `messageText`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hmm.. Looks like the view is populated only after show() and not after create(). However, I tried your code and it works for me. I can see the msg in the center. I tried in Android version 4.1.1

Comment: I thought your code is working. what is the problem now ? The text is aligned to the center of the dialog. Thats what your code does.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything for me. I'm not sure why it would work for you and not for me, maybe I did something else wrong. It should go right before `return builder.create()`, right?

Comment: I have updated the code with a few changes. Check whether this works? First do a show and then setlayoutparams or setGravity.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to change it. It's still aligned left.

Comment: Which version of Android are you in? It worked for in Android 4.1.1. I also tried with both setGravity and setLayoutParams. Sometimes it worked with setGravity and sometimes with setLAyoutParams. It was more consistent with SetGravity call. Cud u try both one after other and check. Strange.. but yes. it worked here.

Comment: I got it working, sort of. It works if I make another builder.show() call after I set the gravity, but that leads to the dialog appearing twice. Anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem...

EDIT: Here are my findings so far: I can get it to work if I add another `builder.show();` call after setting the `messageText`'s gravity, but that leads to another dialog popping up right after closing the first one.

You only have to return your dialog

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show(); 
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
return dialog;
```